# How to change to other desktop environment on VNC sessions?

Tags: desktop-environments, vnc

On my system I will use VNC to login. But at this time, after connect to the pc, I get the automatic login with unity desktop. What I have to do, to have gnome desktop on VNC connection instead of unity?

Answer (score 10):

It should be sufficient to create a suitable `~/.vnc/xstartup` file in your account on the remote host, including the line

```
gnome-session --session=your-preferred-session &
```

For example, a minimal file for a gnome-classic session might be

```
#!/bin/sh

#Uncommment this line if using Gnome and your keyboard mappings are incorrect.
#export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1

# Load X resources (if any)
if [ -r "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
        xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
```

The text of *your-preferred-session* will depend on what desktop packages you have installed - which you can check by looking in the /usr/share/xsessions directory i.e.

```
$ ls /usr/share/xsessions/
awesome.desktop        gnome-classic.desktop  gnome-fallback.desktop
gnome.desktop          gnome-shell.desktop     ubuntu-2d.desktop     xfce.desktop
```

The `xstartup` file can also be used to start non-gnome desktop sessions, for example

```
if which startxfce4 > /dev/null; then
    exec startxfce4 
fi
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, but it isn´t working. I have still unity on vnc sessions. All gnome packages are installed. I think, maybe the "HOME" variable will not set.

Comment: Did you remember to make the ~/.vnc/xstartup file executable e.g. `chmod u+x ~/.vnc/xstartup`?

Comment: Yes, it is executable. But i saw after logout from the local desktop session - for very short time - following: "vncserver: the HOME environment variable is not set". And now i cannot shutdown or reboot the host directly from graphical login screen or when i am logged in via vnc. I must login first local to shutdown the machine.

Comment: Hmm... never seen that error before - what vncserver are you running and how did you install / configure it? How are you invoking it? FWIW think it's normal not to be able to shut down from the GUI when other sessions are active.

Comment: I am using tightvnc. I installed it over the synaptic package manager. Starting it in the /etc/rc.local with following param: `su -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 24" roger` Unfortunatelly i can´t check the log with the message about, because i can´t find the log which was displayed after logout. Maybe do you known which log this is?

Comment: If it's a message from the VNC server it should go into a session log file in `~/.vnc`. Sorry to ask this but since you mention that you are also running a local desktop session (and are not explicitly setting a display number when you invoke the vncserver) - are you sure you are connecting to the vncserver session not the local desktop session (which may be being shared automatically via Vino aka 'Desktop Sharing')?

Comment: FWIW I have never tried running vncserver from rc.local but I can't see why it wouldn't work, and su *should* set $HOME (although I guess you could try `su -l ...` to ensure it is a login environment).

Comment: When i trying with "su -l" - i get following message (in german): "error at authentification"

Comment: Here is my vnc log (~/.vnc/rogerserver:1.log): `vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on port 5801
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element unix/:7100, removing from list!

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: Can't open display ':1'
xsetroot:  unable to open display ':1'`

Comment: `/root/.vnc/xstartup: 7: /root/.vnc/xstartup: twm: not found
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %s`

Comment: [I tried to take this to chat but the system won't let me] I don't understand why you are using **/root**/.vnc/xstartup when you are starting the server as user `roger`. Why not keep things simple for now and just start the vncserver manually from the local session as `roger` so we can see if it works in a more standard configuration?

Comment: So how can I use Unity GUI via VNCviewer/server? Is this heavy and slow?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--replace` in **xstartup** with the session you want to use. It works on Fedora.