# On vnc, stuck on "classic" style desktop

Tags: 16.04, gnome, vnc

I have an "okay" classic-style (no lens, etc) desktop running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.  `gnome` and `ubuntu-desktop` is installed, and I have several desktops available, such as ubuntu.desktop, gnome.desktop, and gnome-classic.desktop.

I would like to run the new gnome that I have on my local desktop, which is Gnome 3 (also perhaps it is called Gnome with the Awesome Desktop).

How can I do that?  Below is the xstartup file that I have now:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

#export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

gnome-session --session=awesome --disable-acceleration-check &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &

pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio -D
```

I've tried all the info at: [How to change to other desktop environment on VNC sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352232/how-to-change-to-other-desktop-environment-on-vnc-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is wrong!

First, you possibly try to start 3 different window managers:
- `x-window-manager` will start default window manager or your pc.
- `gnome-session` will start window manager that is used in Awesome desktop.
- `metacity` you try to explicitly start window manager.

If you want to start full session using `gnome-session` then you should remove `x-terminal-emulator`, `x-window-manager`, `gnome-panel`, `gnome-settings-daemon`, `metacity` and `nautilus`.

If you really want that there is opened terminal and/or file manager window automatically when you start it then you can leave `x-terminal-emulator` and/or `nautilus`, but other things should be removed.

`gnome-session` will start everything you need, but if that will work depends on your desktop. If it requires hardware acceleration then it will not work.

`--disable-acceleration-check` is used to disable this check, but it won't help if acceleration is hard dependency for your desktop.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  I want to go in the direction of `gnome-session` only.  

This is on an ec2 medium.t2 instance, and in the past, these ec2 instances did not have hardware acceleration: One could not run Ubuntu Unity desktop on them because of that, for example.

How can a hard dependency on hardware acceleration be checked for?  If a hard dependency is found, what are places to look for alternatives?

Ideally, I would like to run the Gnome3 Awesome desktop, but I see that, while `awesome.desktop` is listed on my system, it is not directly a gnome desktop.

Comment: Remove `--disable-acceleration-check` and add `--debug`. Then `gnome-session` will do needed things. If session does not start then check ~/.xsession-errors

Comment: Hello,  we removed all the items you mentioned and kept x-window-manager. When we tried with "gnome-session --debug", the screen showed solid gray but with no errors in xsession-errors file. However in syslog file we see : "gnome-session-binary[1502]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1. "  So we further added "--disable-acceleration-check".  With this we see only the wallpaper and nothing more. Then we added "gnome-panel &" and that helped us to get the menu bars showing. The theme of the menu is dark but we do not have a fully fledged Gnome3 UI.