# 18.04.2 minimal installation vnc setup

Tags: 18.04, login, remote-desktop, vnc

I've installed a Dell Precision M4700 with Ubuntu 18.04.2 Desktop in a minimal installation.
I want to now set this up so I can remote login via vnc, using the same desktop environment that comes with the default installation.

I will be VNC'ing from a Windows machine using UltraVNC. It is on the same network as the Ubuntu machine, and I do not need to ssh into the Ubuntu machine - however still want to have remote login via VNC.

What I have tried so far is:

Installing vnc4server, and using the default setup for "xstartup" - This results in my Windows machine connecting however I just get the grey screen with options for vnc configuration ("Accept clipboard from viewers", etc.). Looking at the remote log, I can see that multiple errors occur due to a folder missing - /etc/x11/xserver. I've not been able to determine if this is a warning I can ignore. I've attempted to modify the "xstartup" file as per the link below, but it doesn't change the result - 
[How to change to other desktop environment on VNC sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352232/how-to-change-to-other-desktop-environment-on-vnc-sessions)

Have also tried switching to xrdp/vino - so now connecting via Windows Remote Desktop - this gives me a login window, but when logging in nothing happens (as in the login GUI disappears, and I have a blank screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so focusing a bit on using xrdp instead temporarily, I've now got it working - albeit no longer via vnc...

So used the following websites to guide me on this:
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390 - Got xrdp working, whilst allowing the use of local machines keyboard.

https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043
These two fixed a problem where authentication was required on every remote login.

https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12155
Finally, this link helped with keeping the themes the same.

Even though it's no longer through VNC, I'm still happy now that I can remote login to my Linux machine. I've marked this as the answer, hope this helps anyone who is attempting to remote login for 18.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
$ mkdir $HOME/.vnc
$ echo '#!/bin/bash
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-session &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
# or nautilus-desktop &
## if you need a terminal window: gnome-terminal &
' > $HOME/.vnc/xstartup
$ chmod 755 $HOME/.vnc/xstartup
```

before starting the vncserver.

Feel free to change the last lines of *xstartup* file as needed.

I will also recommend doing

```
$ sudo apt install  gnome-panel gnome
```

to install any missing gnome related packages.

Comment: Could you explain what this update to the xstartup is doing? As I have tried:
{#!/bin/bash
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
}

Comment: That's what I am using in a Debian (not Ubuntu) system. Please, try one by one line to change your _xstartup_ file to match the given sample file. Each time you should first do _vncserver -kill_ before restarting _vncserver_.

Comment: Alright, so status >
The first few lines didn't really much of a change, however, got an error for "gnome-settings-daemon" saying that it's not found. Attempted to install this, but already had the latest installed (3.28.1-0ubuntu1.2) - so have commented it out for now.
metacity - changes the vnc'd cursor from "X" to a cursor.
nautilus - gives me an explorer window! However nothing else
Changing this entry to nautilus-desktop, the window disappears and nothing really changes.
gnome-terminal - just opens a terminal on the Linux machine; doesn't appear within the vnc session.

Comment: Looking over the log, I can see there are a few warnings for "gnome-panel" and "metacity" - 


** (gnome-panel:26024): WARNING **: 19:17:43.641: Failed to request name: the name already has an own
er
metacity-Message: 19:17:43.661: could not find XKB extension.

(metacity:26025): metacity-WARNING **: 19:17:43.664: Failed to create MetaCompositorXRender: Missing 
composite extension required for compositing

Comment: Each configuration (installed programs and their versions) is unique. I am sorry that I cannot help you further.

Comment: unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS just freezes my screen on Ubuntu 18.04. Still can't figure out why