# Why is MSTSC/RDP always defaulting to XFCE and not my Gnome Distro?

Tags: gnome, xfce, remote-desktop

Why is MSTSC/RDP always defaulting to XFCE and not my Gnome Distro?

I ran so many commands and followed so many guides but no matter what I do when I RDP to my linux server I always get XFCe even though I installed teamviewer on Gnome and I can go into that fine using that tool. RDP you can't obviously view the switch user / log out screen.

Comment: Why Xfce? Because Xfce is a lightweight desktop environment for Linux operating system, so more resources will be for your services usage.

Comment: Do you just want to know why, or do you care to change it?  If you want to change it, you'll need to provide more info about the rdp server and config.

Comment: I would like to change it so I RDP straight into Gnome or Ubuntu :) It is a remote server.

Comment: Not sure what you are running as your RDP server, but you might want to see https://askubuntu.com/a/352261/231142